# Coordinates and height, width Unit of iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle method in Itext 7

Tags: c#, itext7

I'm going to extract text from specific rectangle of PDF file
I have used these methods from Itext 7
https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.8/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_geom_1_1_rectangle.html

```
 iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle rect = new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(float x, float y, float width, float height);
 TextRegionEventFilter regionFilter = new TextRegionEventFilter(rect.SetBbox(float x, float y, float width, float height));
```

I do not know what the unit of these coordinate and size of rectangle unit is. That should be inch, mm or cm.
Can you share me what unit should be used ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you already set the desired rectangle in its constructor

```
iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle rect = new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(float x, float y, float width, float height);
```

you don't need to set it again here

```
TextRegionEventFilter regionFilter = new TextRegionEventFilter(rect.SetBbox(float x, float y, float width, float height));
```

you only need

```
TextRegionEventFilter regionFilter = new TextRegionEventFilter(rect);
```

---

That been said, the coordinates are *default user space coordinates*:

> The user space coordinate system shall be initialised to a default state for each page of a document. The **CropBox** entry in the page dictionary shall specify the rectangle of user space corresponding to the visible area of the intended output medium (display window or printed page). The positive *x* axis extends horizontally to the right and the positive *y* axis vertically upward, as in standard mathematical practice (subject to alteration by the **Rotate** entry in the page dictionary). The length of a unit along both the *x* and *y* axes is set by the **UserUnit** entry (PDF 1.6) in the page dictionary (see "Table 31 — Entries in a page object"). If that entry is not present or supported, the default value of 1 ⁄ 72 inch is used. This coordinate system is called default user space.

*(ISO 32000-1 and 32000-2 section 8.3.2.3)*

You can retrieve the entries mentioned from the itext page object in question.